# The resource jumps home after being released instead of using the path

Tags: anylogic

In my model I have used the moveToBy block introduced in the jobshop model. I use this block to deliver the agents(product) to the destination by the resource (forklift). I set all the speed options I saw to one meter per second. The problem that occurs in time of running the model is that the forklift suddenly jumps home after getting rid of the product, while I want the forklift to return home through the path and at the same speed. this is picture of the [moveToBy  block and where I use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0djj.png).

Comment: I replicated the model as shown in your images and the forklift returned home... Feel free to share your model through a link.

Comment: This problem was fixed after I made some changes to the model that were unrelated to the problem. The problem may have been due to incomplete build and no changes in default high speeds.